# mailto: on selected option from selectOneMenu in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, ajax4jsf

I want to implement `mailto:` link in jsf on selected option in `selectOneMenu(dropdown list)`

how can i implement this ?

Comment: can you ellaborate a bit more the question? What's the use case? what's the expected behavior? What's the final HTML code you want to have for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to end up with something like

```
<select>
    <option><a href="mailto:name@example.com">link</a></option>
</select>
```

?

That's already not possible in HTML, so JSF can't do much for you here. Your best bet is to mimic a dropdown with `<div><ul><li>` and a good shot of JavaScript and CSS.

Alternatively, if you can live with non-styleable dropdown options (you can for example not color or underline them, so that they look like links), you can also just add a little shot of JS to achieve your needs.

```
<h:selectOneMenu onchange="var link = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value; if (link) window.location = link;">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select" itemValue="null" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.mailLinks}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Assuming that the item values are already strings with the `mailto:name@example.com` values.

Comment: thanks for gr8 responce...this is nearer to my answer but i have list of contact person and i want to send mail to on selected option from SelectOneMenu....
what thing i have to change ?
and what will be the javascript for it ?

Comment: I don't see any need for changes. Maybe at highest bean and property names?